# How to generate xml using nokogiri builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to build an xml file using nokogiri in rails. The xml is of the below format.

````
<ServiceIncident>
  <Incident>
    <Abstract>linux_bpac_endpoint_scan_v01</Abstract>
    <Description>host=endpoint01.t00.com</Description>
    <FlexFields>
      <FlexField mappedTo="event_class">1</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="ITEM">t00-bpac:endpoint01.t00.com:linux_bpac_endpoint_scan_v01</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="sr_params">{"host":"endpoint01.t00.com"}</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="sr_id">{"REQUEST_ID":"100682"}</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="sr_tool">bpac</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="service_state">1</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="host_state">1</FlexField>
      <FlexField mappedTo="service_type">SR</FlexField>
    </FlexFields>
  </Incident>
</ServiceIncident>```
````

I am unable to generete FlexField. I am trying the below code.

```
 require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.ServiceIncident {
      xml.Incident {
       xml.FlexFields {
         xml.FlexField("mappedTo" => "event_class") { '1' }
       }
      }
    }
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

and this is what I get.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServiceIncident>
  <Incident>
    <FlexFields>
      <FlexField mappedTo="event_class"/>
    </FlexFields>
  </Incident>
</ServiceIncident>
```

I am not able generate the value after mappedTo field. Could you please suggest what needs to be updated in the code so that the xml is generated in the correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Nokogiri code :

```rb
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.ServiceIncident {
    xml.Incident {
     xml.FlexFields {
       xml.FlexField('1', "mappedTo" => "event_class")
     }
    }
  }
end
```

Produces :

```xml
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<ServiceIncident>
  <Incident>
    <FlexFields>
      <FlexField mappedTo=\"event_class\">1</FlexField>
    </FlexFields>
  </Incident>
</ServiceIncident>
```

Was it what you were looking for ?